# What does a faded question means?

Tags: support, questions

Sorry for my ignorance, but What does a faded question means?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to look stupid for 30 seconds, than to be stupid for the rest of your life. Good that you asked!

Faded means you have put the 2010 tag to your ignore tags. Followed tags will highlight in slightly yellowish color.

Comment: You're right, I don't even realize that, but now I'm editing my tag preferences... Thanks!!

Comment: @agzertuche Your welcome! Have fun here!!!